# What is the difference between Intrexx "string" and "text" data fields?

Tags: intrexx

I am currently learning how to use the development environment called Intrexx and I noticed that there are data fields of the "Text" type. What is the difference between string and text data fields?

I tried to look it up but I didn't really find any results. Can someone explain me the difference?

Comment: I rolled back your edit; please see "Don't include tags in the title" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know I wasn't supposed to do that. Thank you!

Comment: that link also contains: "[Before posting a question, we strongly recommend that you spend a reasonable amount of time researching the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Before%20posting%20a%20question%2C%20we%20strongly%20recommend%20that%20you%20spend%20a%20reasonable%20amount%20of%20time%20researching%20the%20problem)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The major difference between the two fields is how many characters you can put in these fields. A string field has a limit of 255 characters, whereas a text field has a character limit of 30,000 characters

found [here](https://nation.marketo.com/t5/knowledgebase/the-difference-between-a-field-type-of-string-and-text/ta-p/250347)